# jsonwebtoken not decoding jwt in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am generating a JWT using IdentityServer4. This is being sent to a SPA using angular. The SPA can decode the token and get the claims e.g. Role.

```
const tokenPayload = jwt_decode(token);
return tokenPayload.role === expectedRole;
```

That same token is being sent to an API in NodeJS. I tried to decode the JWT using jsonwebtoken but I cannot get it to decode it.

```
const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(req);
console.log('Reading token: ' + token);
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'supersecret',
{   
    typ:"JWT",
    algorithms: ["RS256"],
    issuer: 'http://localhost:5500',
audience: 'adApi' } 
        );
    console.log('Decoded token: ' + decoded);
```

I keep getting errors:
"Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

I understand the documentation says I should be using a PEM file instead of 'supersecret'.

Question: Why is it that "jwt_decode" can decode the token so easily? How do I generate the PEM file.

This is the configuration info I am using. Let me remind you that this is ASPNET Core Identity using IdentityServer4.

```
using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XYZ.Identity
{
    public class IdentityServerConfig
    {
        // scopes define the resources in your system
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new[]
                        {
                            new ApiResource
                            {
                                Name = "adApi",
                                DisplayName = "adApi Resource",
                                Description = "XYZ Admin API",
                                ApiSecrets = { new Secret("supersecret".Sha256()) },
                                Scopes = { new Scope("adApi") },
                                UserClaims = {
                                    "name", "role"
                                }
                            }
                        };

        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "apiclientid",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("supersecret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "adApi"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to understand what happened.

1. In the IdentityServer4 implementation for ASP.NET Core there is an "implicit" RSA key/cert being created. The AddDeveloperSigningCredential() in the following code causes the tempkey.rsa file to be created.

   services.AddIdentityServer()
   .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
   //.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(".", "certs", "IdentityServer4Auth.pfx")))
   .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
   .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetIdentityResources())
   .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetApiResources())
   .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.GetClients())
   .AddAspNetIdentity();

This file is used by IdentityServer4 to sign the tokens.

2. In order to verify the token, that is to check if the token has not been tampered with, you need the public key to be generated. For that, you can open the rsa file which is in JSON format and using [this](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter) tool you can generate the PEM content which is the public key.
3. I saved the file in my NodeJS server and used the following code to verify and then decode.

   const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(req);
   console.log('Reading token: ' + token + "==");

   // verify a token asymmetric
   var cert = fs.readFileSync('public-key.pem');  // get public key
   jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
       if(err)
           //Error logic 
       //verify token expire date
       console.log(decoded) // bar
   });

   var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
   var userId = decoded.name;

The trick was to understand that the RSA file was being generated and the the pulic key gad to be generated separately. This might be obvious once you've done it but for new people in the certificates world it might be that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`jwt_decode` just decodes the token without verifying the signature.  There is no need to verify signatures in the frontend, since you never have anything secret there without the backend already verifying authorization.

To try out a signed token with a symmetric signature secret, you need to change the `algorithm` from `RS256` to a symmetric one, like `HS256` (for `verify` you can add it to the array of allowed algorithms).

Comment: I have tried with that algorithm and get the same result: "JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm". I am Editing the question to reflect how I am creating the token.

Comment: I don't know about the aspnet code, but the HS256 only uses the secret.  This might depend on your library, but you're using a Sha256 of the string to make the signing secret.  The error about PEM in your question is based on RS256 that is in your code as algorithm...  Perhaps IdentityServer4 always uses RS256, I don't see you setting algorithm in the ASPNET code...

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer above, I did the experiment, and I couldn't reply directly to the above answer, because I was not enough, so I had to reply directly.

I write code according to the identityserver4 demo example, the use of.AddDeveloperSigningCredential (), so I see tempkey.rsa in the identityserver4 server project, I use Notepad to open, and copy the Modulus data, and then use the https:// superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter tool to generate the PEM file, then I use the following code in express middleware. PEM file, I just generated PEM files. Then I successfully verified the token issued by identityserver4

```
Var cert = fs.readFileSync ('demo2.pem');
Jwt.verify (token, Cert, function (err, decoded) {
If (ERR) {
Console.log (ERR);
}else{
Console.log (decoded);
//Error logic //verify token expire date} console.log (decoded / bar)
});
```

But there are a few questions here

1, we should not take the modules data to generate PEM, and then copied to the nodejs project, because it is not the best solution, if we modify the idrv4 server key, we must rebuild the PEM file, and then copied to the server corresponding to the nodejs, it was stupid. I checked some information, you can see the secret key encryption to http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks through this address, but there is a huge bug, that I see in the browser open the contents of the above are as follows

```
{
Keys: [
{
Kty: "RSA",
Use: "sig",
Kid: "4df1e1f19d477d97efeffe3548418c60",
E: "AQAB",
N: "**XXXX**",
Alg: "RS256"
}
]
}
```

But the modules data in the tempkey.rsa file I opened with my notepad was
**XXXX==**
Because in fact the data of modules should be the same as the data shown on the above n, but through
 access to N data, even than the data inside modules, less **==** the 2 character, when I was in front of PEM documents generated by this thing to pit miserable.

2, so we still need to get nodejs's API to start up, get the key inside http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks, and then generate PEM files to verify token signature. But to pay attention to the absence of government. But if your idrv4 uses other encryption methods, such as x509 and so on, the key will not be the value of n. It may be something else. I haven't studied it clearly yet.

and last i found npm package jwk-to-pem
you can get keys from http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('file-system');
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');

var pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
console.log(pem);

// verify a token asymmetric 
jwt.verify(token, pem, function(err, decoded) { 
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(decoded);
    } //Error logic //verify token expire date console.log(decoded) // bar 
});
```

Comment: i find a npm package